# Iterate over row and create batch: DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame with millions of row and I am iterating over them using following code:

```
df.foreachPartition { dataSetPartition => {
    dataSetPartition.foreach(row => {
        // DO SOMETHING like DB write/ s3 publish
    })
}
}
```

Now I want to create batch operation for rows, so I change code with

```
df.foreachPartition { dataSetPartition => {
    val rowBuffer = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Row]()
    dataSetPartition.foreach(row => {
        rowBuffer += row
        if (rows.size == 1000) {
            // DO ACTION like DB write/s3 publish  <- DO_ACTION
            rowBuffer.clear
        }
    })
    if (rowBuffer.size > 0) {
            // DO ACTION like DB write/s3 publish  <-DO_ACTION
            rowBuffer.clear
    }
}
}
```

Problem in this approach is that *DO_ACTION* is repeated twice. I do not want to call *dataSetPartition*.size to get row count beforehand as it is lazy evaluated and might be costly operation.

```
Version: 
Scala: 2.11
Spark: 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use Scalas `grouped` method to create batches :

```
df.foreachPartition { dataSetPartition => {
  dataSetPartition.grouped(1000).foreach(batch => {
    // DO ACTION like DB write/s3 publish  <- DO_ACTION
  })
 }
}
```